# Lemma 13.131.10 of Stacks Project — Exact sequence of Kähler differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

There's a tiny step in the proof of [Lemma 10.131.10](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02HP) that was omitted that I can't quite see. Stack's Project says that $D \colon S \to I /I^2$, where $x \mapsto x-\beta (\alpha(x))$, and $I$ is the kernel of the split surjective map $S \to S^\prime$, is an $R$-derivation; how does the argument go to actually show that $D$ is an $R$-derivation? I know it's an explicit computation, however, don't see the little trick I think there is to show that it is an $R$-derivation.

Comment: Alternatively, you can read Matsumura's proof, see [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02HP#comment-8559).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let’s summarize: you have a surjection of $R$-algebras $\alpha: S \rightarrow S’$ with kernel $I$, and a section $\beta: S’ \rightarrow S$ over $R$ as well, and you want to show that $D: s \in S \longmapsto s-\beta(\alpha(s)) \in I/I^2$ is an $R$-derivation.

First, $D$ is clearly well-defined (because $\alpha(x -\beta(\alpha(x)))=0$), and as clearly $R$-linear.

Moreover, if $x,y \in S$, $D(xy)=[xy-\beta(\alpha(xy))]_{I/I^2}=x[y-\beta(\alpha(y))]_{I/I^2}+\beta(\alpha(y))[x-\beta(\alpha(x))]_{I/I^2}$. But $\beta(\alpha(y))-y \in I$ so $\beta(\alpha(y))$ acts the same as $y$ on $I/I^2$, therefore $\beta(\alpha(y))[x-\beta(\alpha(x))]_{I/I^2}=y[x-\beta(\alpha(x))]_{I/I^2}$ and $D(xy)=xD(y)+yD(x)$.

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Thank you!